# Pigtail Line Side of GFCI

Tags: wiring, gfci, irrigation, relay

Is it O.K. to put a pigtail on the line side of an outdoor GFCI to power an irrigation pump (via relay)? The outlet would be used for the irrigation controller and misc. outdoor electrical items.

The GFCI has a dedicated breaker and nothing else downstream. I'll use liquid-tight box to box with sealed connectors and an "in-use" cover for the GFCI box.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware they're are separate terminals for line/load as I am for why a GFCI would be a good thing. I haven't seen any hardwired irrigation pumps on a GFCI and the code is very ambiguous. I'm getting ready to replace the GFCI and pump start relay for a second time so it's not just a matter of "if you have it, use it". There's a place for GFCI's I don't think we need to run out and put them on everything, unless there's a code I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

No! That is what the **load** side is for. An irrigation pump is a perfect use case for protection with GFCI:

- Outdoors
- Water
- Unlike a refrigerator, fire alarm panel, etc. not critical if it were to be shut off due to a GFCI trip (e.g., if something else plugged in tripped the GFCI - obviously if the pump itself tripped the GFCI that would be a good outcome).

So whether it is technically required to be GFCI-protected (which I suspect it is) or not, you have the GFCI available, **use it**.

The only situations where it makes sense to pigtail line off an outside GFCI are lighting (generally exempt from GFCI requirements because the fixtures are out of easy reach) and indoor receptacles (if the power loops back indoors to an ordinary room that doesn't require GFCI - e.g., bedroom, living room, etc.) But even in those cases, GFCI protection doesn't *hurt*, though there is a slight preference for lighting to *not* be GFCI protected so that if you have a problem with the outdoor circuit at night, you still have the lights on.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a downline circuit to either side of a GFCI, and you don't even need pigtails to do it.  Most GFCIs provide a way to attach 2 wires under each screw; read the instructions.

If you attach the downline circuit to the "Line" terminals, the downline will not have GFCI protection.

If you attach the downline circuit to the "Load" terminals, the downline will be protected by this GFCI device. In fact, the "Load" terminals should never be used for any other purpose.

And further, no one should ever use "Load" unless they know exactly what they are doing.  A great many GFCI problems arise because novices use the "Load" terminals *simply because they need 2 more screws*.  They have no idea what Load does, and they have no idea they are protecting  that downline.

Some would argue "a safe thing done by accident is still safer", but **security at the expense of usability is at the expense of security**. When they realize how much trouble GFCI is causing them,  they will be inclined to remove it, or at least, stop installing them.

It is also a Code violation to protect a receptacle outlet without  knowing  you are protecting it, since you are not doing  the required marking from NEC 110.3/8c and 406.4.

Comment: But isn't an irrigation pump - outside, water (either directly or, if actually relay controlled, nearby) - a good use case for GFCI?

Comment: Even in the 2020 NEC code GFI is not necessary for hardwired pumps even if in wet locations, 120v or 240v. Tried finding a 240v 15amp combo unit, impossible.